# Finding the perimeter of the triangle $ABC$

Tags: geometry

> $ABC$ is a triangle where $AE$ and $EB$ are angle bisectors, $|EC| = 5$, $|DE| = 3$, $|AB| = 9$. Find the perimeter of the triangle $ABC$.
>   [image]

I realized that the length of the side $|DC| = 8$. In the $\triangle BEC$, we have special triangle $3-4-5$. This is where I'm stuck. Can I take your thinkings?

Comment: Do you mean the perimeter of the triangle?

Comment: @RobertZ What's the difference between them? Are their answers same?

Comment: @RobertZ Do we get different answer when we want to find the circumference?

Comment: What is the EXACT statement of the problem? The perimeter of a triangle is the sum of the lengths of its sides. What is the circumference of a triangle?

Comment: @RobertZ The exact statement of the problem is what is the perimeter of this triangle? So, do we get a different value if we want to find the circumference? For circumference, I got the answer as $26$, for perimeter, $24$.

Comment: Then, first of all you should edit the question and replace "circumference" with "perimeter". What do you mean by "the circumference a triangle"?

Comment: @RobertZ I've written circumference of triangle in the question which I sent my teacher and he found the answer as $26.2$ using trigonometry. That's hence I'm asking.

Comment: Given a triangle there are various related  circumferences: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incircle_and_excircles_of_a_triangle 
Which one?

Comment: @RobertZ Speaking for this question.

Comment: I don't see any  circumference in your picture...

Comment: @RobertZ Yes but the thing is he found the answer as $26.2$, Is that because I've written circumference instead of perimeter? He also used trigonometry, which is not needed.

Comment: The perimeter is $24$. I don't know what $26.2$ is. Again "circumference of a triangle" means nothing.

Comment: @RobertZ I know but I just wrote circumference instead of perimeter, thereby he found the answer as $26.2$ and I'm asking is that because I wrote the wrong term?

Comment: I don't know. Why don't you ask him?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

$|DE|=3=u$,
$|EC|=5=v$,
$|AB|=9=c$.

The question is not that innocent, as it looks at first glance.

Yes, following 
the angle bisector theorem
we can calculate that 
$|BC|+|AC|=15$ and
$|AB|+|BC|+|AC|=24$, 
as it was shown in the other answers.

But the question is,
is it possible to construct 
a triangle with claimed properties?

Let $r,R$ be the radii 
of inscribed and circumscribed circles
of $\triangle ABC$, respectively,
and let $\rho=\tfrac12(|AB|+|BC|+|AC|)=12$.

\begin{align}
\triangle CEG:\quad
r&=v\sin\tfrac\gamma2
,\\
\text{on the other hand, in }\triangle ABC\quad
r&=(\rho-c)\tan\tfrac\gamma2
,\\
\text{hence }\quad
\cos\tfrac\gamma2&=
\frac{\rho-c}{v}=\frac35
,\\
\sin\tfrac\gamma2&=\frac45
,\\
r&=4
,\\
\sin\gamma&=2\cdot\frac35\cdot\frac45=\frac{24}{25}
,\\
R&=\frac{c}{2\sin\gamma}
=\frac{9}{2\cdot\tfrac{24}{25}}
=\frac{75}{16}
.
\end{align}

So far, so good. But, the validity test:
\begin{align}
\frac{r}{R}
&=\frac{4\cdot16}{75}
=\frac{64}{75}\approx 0.85
\end{align}

shows that this ratio
is bigger than the known maximum for triangles,
$\max\frac{r}{R}=0.5$.

We can actually calculate 
the sided of this "triangle", 
given that the known $\rho,r$ and $R$ 
uniquely define the sides
of the triangle as the roots of cubic polynomial

\begin{align}
x^3-2\rho x^2+(\rho^2+r^2+4r\,R)x-4r\,\rho\,R&=0
,\\
x^3-24x^2+235x-900 &=0
,\\
x_1&=9
,\\
x_{2,3}&=
\tfrac{15}2\pm\tfrac{5\sqrt7}2\cdot i
.
\end{align}

Indeed, the sum of the two other "sides" is $15$,
but they are not real.

Thus, the answer is: **a triangle with claimed properties does not exist.**

**Edit**

In the following illustration, $|AB|=9$,
and the locus of points $C$ is the ellipse with
foci $A,B$ and $|CA|+|CB|=15$.
The green line is the locus of points $D\in AB:\ |CD|=8$,
the red curve is the locus of points 
$E\in CD:\ |CE|=5,\,|ED|=3$,
and the blue curve is the locus of 
the centers $I$ of inscribed circles of 
corresponding triangles $ABC$.

The blue and red curves does not intersect,
and $E=I$ never holds.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A simpler proof that such a triangle cannot exist, as also claimed by @g.kov.

The [locus of points](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/LocusCircle.shtml) $P$ such that $PC/PD=5/3$ is a circle of radius $7.5$ passing through $E$ and with center on line $CD$. Hence $A$ and $B$ must belong to that circle and $AB$ is a chord passing through $D$.

But the shortest such chord is the one perpendicular to $CD$ ($HI$ in diagram below), whose length is $12$. Hence $AB$ cannot have length $9$ as stated in the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well this is a pretty straightforward question.

Now, According to the angle bisector theorem:

> Consider a triangle ABC. Let the angle bisector of angle A intersect side BC at a point D between B and C. The angle bisector theorem states that the ratio of the length of the line segment BD to the length of segment DC is equal to the ratio of the length of side AB to the length of side AC

We get $$AC/AD=BC/BD=5/3$$
$$AC=(5/3)AD$$ and $$BC=(5/3)BD$$
Note that $$AB=AD+DB=9$$

Hence $$AC+BC==(5/3)(AD=DB)=15$$

But circumference of Triangle $=AB+BC+CA=15+9=24$

Comment: I found the circumference as $26.2$ using trigonometry. Is it correct?

Comment: I would be privileged to point out your mistake if you shared your approach in a new post. Answer is 24 without doubt.

Comment: @Anmol Agarwal: Since such triangle is impossible, this answer is incorrect.